Watch only Bitcoin address in Sparrow
The task seems easy, yet it’s very hard to complete. I want to watch a Bitcoin address in Sparrow. It’s a multisig address starting with 3*. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
New Wallet
Policy Type: Single Signature
Script Type: Nested Segwit or Legacy (neither works)
Master Fingerprint: 00000000
Derivation: m/49’/0’/0’
xpub: Bitcoin address starting with 3.. (e.g., 33WVxauW21vZEXn2r7gxAbENLRnwtVeWou)
The “Apply” button never becomes active. Something seems to be wrong.

A Bitcoin address and an xpub are different things.

Thanks for the quick answer, Murch. I’m aware of this and thought watch-only might still be possible (like Electrum does, for example). I assume it’s not achievable this way or even possible.

My guess would be that when you put the P2SH address into the xpub field, Sparrow doesn’t make the "Apply" button active, because a P2SH address is not an xpub. Perhaps you could try to go back to the original wallet that you are trying to watch and look for a way to export the xpub instead of the address.

This seems to be the only way. According to Sparrow Devs watch only with just the address is not possible.
